# Mysql query to join 5 stock tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables; debt_equity, dividend_yeild, market_cap, market_data, and p_e_ratio. I want to join them, each table has a company symbol column. I want to do a query and join these 5 tables
that would be fast.
I tried

```
SELECT *, _pe.date as pe_date, _md.Close, _mc.price as market_cap_price, yield FROM `debt_equity` m
INNER join p_e_ratio _pe on _pe.company = m.company
INNER join market_data _md on _md.company = m.company
INNER join market_cap _mc on _mc.company = m.company
INNER join dividend_yield _y on _y.company = m.company 
where m.date >'2020-03-31' and m.date < '2020-06-31' 
and m.price < 1 and _pe.date >'2020-03-31' and _pe.date < '2020-06-31' and _pe.ratio < 30
and _md.Close >= 15 and _md.date_time >'2020-03-31' and _md.date_time < '2020-06-31'
and _mc.company = m.company and _mc.price > 2000 and _mc.date >'2020-03-31' and _mc.date < '2020-06-31'and  _mc.date <= m.date
and _y.yield > 8  and _y.date >'2020-03-31' and _y.date < '2020-06-31'
GROUP by m.company order by m.company asc
```

But it's too slow

My updated sql query the performance is better added more indexing

```
SELECT *, _pe.date as pe_date, _mc.price as market_cap_price, yield FROM `debt_equity` m
INNER join p_e_ratio _pe on _pe.company = m.company and (_pe.date >= DATE_sub(m.date, INTERVAL 10 day ) and _pe.date <= m.date)  and _pe.ratio < 30
INNER join market_cap _mc on _mc.company = m.company and (_mc.date >= DATE_sub(m.date, INTERVAL 30 day ) and _mc.date <= m.date) and _mc.price > 2000
INNER join dividend_yield _y on _y.company = m.company and (_y.date >= DATE_sub(m.date, INTERVAL 10 day ) and _y.date <= m.date) and _y.yield > 8

INNER join market_data _md on _md.company = m.company and (_md.date_time >= DATE_sub(m.date, INTERVAL 2 day ) and _md.date_time <= DATE_add(m.date, INTERVAL 2 day )) and  _md.Close >= 15
where m.date >'2020-03-31' and m.date < '2020-07-31' and m.price < 1
GROUP by m.company order by m.company ASC
```

Comment: Try to apply the corresponding filters during join rather than filtering data after all joins

Comment: How would I go about that? An example would be great

Comment: How many rows in result dataset? Does `company` columns have indexes?

Comment: By moving the `where` conditions about the joined tables in the `on` clause concerning this table, an exemple `on (_pe.company = m.company and _pe.ratio < 30)` and removing `_pe.ratio < 30` from the `where`

Comment: @mrNone a few millions and yes `company` columns have indexes

Comment: Why do you have the join conditions both in the ON clause and the WHERE clause? `_mc.company = m.company` is in both places.

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the other columns too? price, close, dates, etc? I don't think there is much else that would help a lot.

Comment: There is no aggregate function. So the datas  of selected columns are inconstant. What result do you want?

Comment: Good point @etsuhisa. This query shouldnt run anyway due to the group by on a single column. Also no need to select all columns using `select *`, then add columns that are also included in the [*].

Comment: @TomC updated and removed it. Yes, I have indexed all the columns. prices, company, and dates columns. and has greatly improved performance